# How to add index to paragraph template

Tags: theming, paragraphs

I want to use paragraphs to implement a carousel, and for now, I have the outer paragraph called slideshow, and the template is paragraph--slideshow.html.twig.
Then, inside this paragraph, I can add slides, and the template is paragraph--slide.html.twig.

At the moment, I only have the default paragraphs template which looks like this:

```
{%
  set classes = [
    'paragraph',
    'paragraph--type--' ~ paragraph.bundle|clean_class,
    view_mode ? 'paragraph--view-mode--' ~ view_mode|clean_class,
    not paragraph.isPublished() ? 'paragraph--unpublished'
  ]
%}

{% block paragraph %}
  <div{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
    {% block content %}
      {{ content }}
    {% endblock %}
  </div>
{% endblock paragraph %}
```

**Problem:** When I view the page in the front-end, all slide divs have the exact same properties.

Question: How do I count a display the number of paragraphs of the same type?
Is there a way to add indexing?

The html should look like this:

```
<div class="paragaph-1 other_classes"></div>
<div class="paragaph-2 other_classes"></div>
<div class="paragaph-3 other_classes"></div>
<div class="paragaph-4 other_classes"></div>
```

Comment: You have to look what's inside `{{ content }}`. Install the Twig Tweak module and then print `{{ dd() }}` inside your template. The slides are probably somewhere in `{{ content.field_slides|field_value }}` or similar. Get the field items, loop, build the markup and attach libraries as you need it. Maybe enable Twig debugging first. Read https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/twig-in-drupal/discovering-and-inspecting-variables-in-twig-templates and https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/twig-in-drupal/debugging-twig-templates.

Comment: Yes, this is one way, but bypassing the field template can have some unwanted side-effects. Better render `{{ content }}` as it is and use the resulting field template to output the index and adjust the CSS to the template structure. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/244152/getting-index-of-item-in-items-inside-twig-template